The proof of asymptotic Giibert-Varshamov lower bound
In a book, the Gilbert-Varshamov lower bound is given as follow.
Suppose $0 \leq \delta < \frac{1}{2}$. Then there exists an infinite sequence of $[n,k,d]$ binary linear code with $d/n \geq \delta$ and rate $R=k/n$ satisfying $R \geq 1-H_{2}(d/n)$ for all $n$.
By Varshamov lower bound, I can show that if $0 \leq \delta < \frac{1}{2}$ and $R \leq 1 - H_{2}(\delta)$, then there exists a binary code with rate $\geq R$ and relative distance $\geq \delta$.
But how this relates to the above theorem?
Or, is there the other way to prove it?
